# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER' error

Tags: c#, sql, syntax

This query is working in sql management studio but i am getting this error in visual studio:
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'"

```
SELECT MakaleKatDil.KategoriAdi, Makale.Id, Makale.Aktif, Makale.AnasayfadaGoster, Makale.GosterimSirasi, Makale.MakaleKategori_Id, MakaleDil.Baslik, MakaleDil.Resim
FROM Makale INNER JOIN
     MakaleDil ON Makale.Id = MakaleDil.MakaleId INNER JOIN
     MakaleKatDil ON Makale.Id = MakaleKatDil.Id INNER JOIN
     MakaleKategori ON Makale.MakaleKategori_Id = MakaleKategori.Id AND
     MakaleKatDil.MakaleKategori_Id = MakaleKategori.Id
```

[image]
what is the problem ?

thank you all. it is working now. missed a blank between MakaleDil.Resim and FROM

Comment: The SQL you've shown in the question isn't the SQL in the string. Hint: print out the string or look at it in the debugger, and you'll see the problem. This is why it's useful to provide the *code* (as text, not images) rather than what you think the code has done.

Comment: You missed a blank between `MakaleDil.Resim` and `FROM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the string you are building - you need a space after MakaleDil.Resim. Without it becomes MakaleDil.ResimFROM

Answer (score 3):

You are lacking a space right before `FROM`.

Comment: @erenn: you are welcome; please do not hesitate to accept one of the answers :-)